Is there a way to add a "consultant" role in a Salesforce approval process?
Is there a way in Salesforce for, when a case is submitted for approval, for certain people to provide an opinion (e.g. thumbs up or down), but for their opinion to have no effect on the final approval/rejection of the process? In this case, the final approver, for example, would see that he got 4 thumbs up and 2 thumbs down, but ultimately he decides to reject the request. I know that these could be just notes added to it, but wondering if there is a more systematic way to add a vote and have the approver understand it without having to read through the details.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  There's no out-of-the-box feature for that; you'll have to build it custom .
